# Remove duplicate rows and add count

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying add a count column to my table. I want to remove duplicate rows and add an additional column with the count of rows removed.

My Table looks like this:

```
start             institution_code  year
Indianapolis, IN    IUBLA           2004
Indianapolis, IN    IUBLA           2004
Indianapolis, IN    IUINA           2004
Bloomington,  IN    IUINA           2002
Bloomington,  IN    IUINA           2002
```

And I'd like the final version to look like this:

```
start             institution_code  year    Count
Indianapolis, IN    IUBLA           2004    2
Indianapolis, IN    IUINA           2004    1
Bloomington,  IN    IUINA           2002    2
```

I thought come combination of `Count` and `Group By` or even `Over` but I haven't been able to come up with a working example.

```
                                              version                                                 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 PostgreSQL 10.7 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-23), 64-bit
```

Answer (score 2):

It should be a pretty straight forward **group by** and **count**:

```
select start, institution_code  , year, count(*) as Count
from yourtable
group by start, institution_code  , year;
```